# Pull request reverted

Tags: git, github, merge, rebase, revert

In my repository, there was a pull request (`183`, from branch `A`) that I merged (in github's page) by mistake. I noticed in the same moment, so I pressed the button `revert` on github's page and it generated another pull request, in my name, id: `184` (branch `Revert-A`). So thinking it would fix things, I accepted my PR.

However, the branch `A` is under validation and probably will be soon integrated with the main branch as is. So, I tried to reopen the PR, picking branch `A` and opening a new PR. However I'm getting the message:

> There isn’t anything to compare.

Probably because all changes on branch `A` are already on the history of the master branch, and the `Revert-A`, instead of just undoing my merge, created a new commit undoing what was done on branch `A`.

I wonder how can I undo my mistake. Should I rebase branch `A` and try to create a new PR? Or maybe try to reset the head? What would be the best option (or at least one that would actually fix my mess)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you revert, it creates the "anti" commit of the one you're reverting.  When you acceptrf commit `183`, it pushed the changes to the main branch.  You now need to also push `184` to revert those changes.  Then you can create another revert for the revert for your PR.  If you simply try to submit `183` again, that will not work as the main branch will see that the commit is (rightfully) already there, it just happens to be reverted later.

Rebasing or reseting the head on the main branch is typically not good practice, as it would mess with anyone's local repos when they try to fetch the remote.

Comment: So, you think, when the validation finish, I should revert my revert PR? But, what if the validation fails, and something else needs to be added to branch `A`?

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado Yes, you should create a PR to revert the revert, if you want a PR of the original changes. If validation passed with the original commit, then the first revert should not have issues.  If the revert-revert has issues, then you'll need another commit.  If changes have happened on top of 183 that weren't yours, and now validation fails, you can revert those as well, and then revert-revert them too.  Sorry, I realize this is tough to explain with the commit history.

Comment: It is a little confusing, but I got it :) thanks a lot. If it works, I'll accept your answer.